# Compilation error building archive version of MASS on macOS

Tags: c++, r, macos

I'm trying to build and install `MASS` 7.3-54 (for restoring a `renv` environment) under R 4.1.2 on macOS 11.7.7.  I thought the issue might be an old version of `clang` (was something like 12.5, I think), but removing and reinstalling the Xcode Command Line Tools didn't resolve things.

```
* installing *source* package ‘MASS’ ...
** package ‘MASS’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
using C compiler: ‘Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)’
using SDK: ‘MacOSX12.1.sdk’
clang -arch x86_64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/opt/R/x86_64/include    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c MASS.c -o MASS.o
MASS.c:37:23: error: unknown type name 'Sint'; did you mean 'int'?
VR_sammon(double *dd, Sint *nn, Sint *kd, double *Y, Sint *niter,
                      ^~~~
                      int
MASS.c:37:33: error: unknown type name 'Sint'; did you mean 'int'?
VR_sammon(double *dd, Sint *nn, Sint *kd, double *Y, Sint *niter,
                                ^~~~
                                int
MASS.c:37:54: error: unknown type name 'Sint'; did you mean 'int'?
VR_sammon(double *dd, Sint *nn, Sint *kd, double *Y, Sint *niter,
                                                     ^~~~
                                                     int
MASS.c:38:20: error: unknown type name 'Sint'; did you mean 'int'?
          double *stress, Sint *trace, double *aa, double *tol)
                          ^~~~
                          int
MASS.c:168:8: error: unknown type name 'Sint'; did you mean 'int'?
static Sint *ord;               /* ranks of dissimilarities */
       ^~~~
       int
MASS.c:169:8: error: unknown type name 'Sint'; did you mean 'int'?
static Sint *ord2;              /* inverse ordering (which one is rank i?) */
       ^~~~
       int
MASS.c:170:8: error: unknown type name 'Sint'; did you mean 'int'?
static Sint n;                  /* number of  dissimilarities */
       ^~~~
       int
MASS.c:171:8: error: unknown type name 'Sint'; did you mean 'int'?
static Sint nr;                 /* number of data points */
       ^~~~
       int
MASS.c:172:8: error: unknown type name 'Sint'; did you mean 'int'?
static Sint nc;                 /* # cols of  fitted configuration */
       ^~~~
       int
MASS.c:181:31: error: unknown type name 'Sint'; did you mean 'int'?
VR_mds_fn(double *, double *, Sint *, double *, Sint *,
                              ^~~~
                              int
MASS.c:181:49: error: unknown type name 'Sint'; did you mean 'int'?
VR_mds_fn(double *, double *, Sint *, double *, Sint *,
                                                ^~~~
                                                int
MASS.c:182:14: error: unknown type name 'Sint'; did you mean 'int'?
          double *, Sint *, Sint *, double *, Sint *, double *);
                    ^~~~
                    int
MASS.c:182:22: error: unknown type name 'Sint'; did you mean 'int'?
          double *, Sint *, Sint *, double *, Sint *, double *);
                            ^~~~
                            int
MASS.c:182:40: error: unknown type name 'Sint'; did you mean 'int'?
          double *, Sint *, Sint *, double *, Sint *, double *);
                                              ^~~~
                                              int
MASS.c:188:18: error: unknown type name 'Sint'; did you mean 'int'?
VR_mds_init_data(Sint *pn, Sint *pc, Sint *pr, Sint *orde,
                 ^~~~
                 int
MASS.c:188:28: error: unknown type name 'Sint'; did you mean 'int'?
VR_mds_init_data(Sint *pn, Sint *pc, Sint *pr, Sint *orde,
                           ^~~~
                           int
MASS.c:188:38: error: unknown type name 'Sint'; did you mean 'int'?
VR_mds_init_data(Sint *pn, Sint *pc, Sint *pr, Sint *orde,
                                     ^~~~
                                     int
MASS.c:188:48: error: unknown type name 'Sint'; did you mean 'int'?
VR_mds_init_data(Sint *pn, Sint *pc, Sint *pr, Sint *orde,
                                               ^~~~
                                               int
MASS.c:189:4: error: unknown type name 'Sint'; did you mean 'int'?
                 Sint *ordee, double *xx, double *p)
                 ^~~~
                 int
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [MASS.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘MASS’
```

Comment: I’m not the downvoter. However, I would have thought a full description of your compiler tools would be needed. Did you for instance use the versions of clang and Fortran from the canonical repository or did you brew it?

Comment: Sorry; I'm basically completely ignorant about the compiler side of things here.  I just run `xcode-select --install`.  `xcode-select --version` returns 2384.  Happy to provide other essential information if you tell me how to generate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is admittedly a guess.

Your error doesn't look like a compiler version problem to me: the message says specifically that the type name `Sint` is unknown. The R NEWS file states that [as of R 4.3.0](https://github.com/r-devel/r-svn/blob/master/doc/NEWS.Rd#L701-L704)

> The deprecated legacy typedefs of `Sint` and `Sfloat` in header `R.h` are no longer defined ...

(they were deprecated in R 4.2.1); see [this commit](https://github.com/r-devel/r-svn/commit/36a143b87c45e5b719acb2173d9dc0c12b4c5e23). It seems most likely to me that you're accidentally compiling against a set of header files from R 4.3.0 or later ... I would suggest checking the `R.h` files living in the 'include' directories specified in the compiler call (`/opt/R/x86_64/include` and `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include`). (The copies of `R.h` in my system directories do not have explicit version numbers included in them, alas, but you can grep/search the files for the string "Sint" — it should be there somewhere around line 90 if you have an old-enough version ...)

Comment: Doesn't "/usr/local/opt/" suggest a Homebrew installation of R or C??

Comment: What a great idea to remove something and break backward compat on a minor release.

Answer (score 5):

I’m not going to answer the original question but rather attempt what is probably a partial answer to the question at the end of you comment: "Happy to provide other essential information if you tell me how to generate it."

Your system needs to be constructed as of a particular date that would probably be extracted from the Package Archives page for MASS. (perhaps `MASS_7.3-54.tar.gz  2021-05-03 11:03` pulled from the package's archive directory. One month after that date the R Developer for MacOS page said:

> R-4.1.0.pkg (notarized and signed)
> SHA1-hash: df4d6fc17bbf6b7a27d4e015c0084d4bb6f7b428
> (ca. 87MB)  R 4.1.0 binary for macOS 10.13 (High Sierra) and higher, Intel 64-bit build, ).

... which addresses BenBolker's question , I think.

You should be studying the R-FAQ that was current at the time of your version of MASS. You will probably also need to study “Writing R Extensions”.  Your sketchy description of your setup might be filled out by including output of `sessionInfo()` and `Sys.getenv()`. ( I am not able to either pull off the top of my head, or even tell you where to find such,  the numbers of the OS and compiler versions that were current and internally consistent as of any particular date two years ago, so you may need to assemble that from other sources.) I will observe that the numbers hint as some level of discrepancy, but I don't remember if Apple keeps leading digits of their sdk, compiler and OS versions consistent, but I did find this on an Apple developer page:

> The macOS 12.1 SDK provides support to develop apps for Mac computers running macOS Monterey 12.1. The SDK comes bundled with Xcode 13.2,

... which makes me think you're inconsistent with regard to sdk and OS versions.
From the current https://mac.r-project.org/ page:

> Changes since R 4.3.0 Builds

> R 4.3.0 CRAN builds are using Xcode 14.2/14.3, macOS 11.3 SDK and targeting macOS 11 (Big Sur) and GNU Fortran 12.2. This is now true for both x86_64 and arm64 builds. The corresponding package types (.Platform$pkgType) are "mac.binary.big-sur-x86_64" for Intel and "mac.binary.big-sur-arm64" for Apple silicon Macs.

The info at https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#Installation-of-source-packages shows a typical Makeconf file and that would probably need to be located in a version of that page that was current as of whatever target date you specify. You might try the Internet Archive's site, i.e. Wayback Machine.

Sometimes you can get knowledgeable answers to such questions on SO but other times you will need to subscribe to the R-SIG-Mac mailing list which is viewed by people who might be able to generate a good answer if and only if you provide all of the above information.

Comment: Very nice and patient answer.

Comment: You made my day, Dirk. I kept saying to myself as I tried to assemble it "what would Dirk or Simon want me to include?"